# Random java.util.NoSuchElementException even with using wait()

Tags: java, multithreading, linked-list, wait

Could you please tell me in which case this code throw a java.util.NoSuchElementException :

```
public class StackTest {

    private LinkedList<Object> myList = new LinkedList<Object>();
    public StackTest() {

        Thread testStack = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true)
                { 
                    synchronized (myList)
                    {
                        try {
                            if (myList.size() == 0)
                            {
                                myList.wait();
                            }
                            Object elem = myList.removeLast();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        testStack.start();
    }

    public void enQueue(Object o)
    {
        synchronized(myList)
        {
            myList.addFirst(o);
            myList.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

My loop is always waiting for the enqueue method to invoke the notifyAll after adding an element. But from time to time, I have a java.util.NoSuchElementException when calling `myList.removeLast()`

Comment: If there is no more entry in your list?

Comment: if there is no entry size will be 0 and program will wait ?
if (myList.size() == 0)
{
      myList.wait();
 }

Comment: If the `wait` is done but `myList` is still empty... Are you sure that `wait` will only happen when `enQueue` is called ?

Comment: Why are you using a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) and manually implementing wait-for-element, when you get that functionality for free using a [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html), or any of the other [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementations?

Comment: Yes I am sure that notify happen only when enQueue is called.

Comment: Just have some read about BlockingQueue and it could be an alternative in our future developments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should stick to [the recommended pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait-long-int-) and put your condition in a `while` to avoid spurious wakeups.

```
synchronized (myList) {
    try {
        while (myList.size() == 0) {
            myList.wait();
        }
        Object elem = myList.removeLast();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Yes I will definitely put my condition in a while. My question is about these spurious wakeups. In my example, what kind of wakeups could happen when I am sure that only enQueue method invoke the notify.

Comment: @Youss It's explained in the link I posted. `wait` may return even if `notify` hasn't been called. Note that another possible reason for your problem is if you call `notify` in your code in a place that you haven't shown in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line of code is no longer protected by the synchronized :

```
Object elem = myList.removeLast();
```

calling wait() on the list releases the ownership of the lock so another thread can reach the notify part of your code. This also means that multiple threads can be waiting - and be notified at once. These will then concurrently try to execute the removeLast() on your list - which will result in your described error if more threads are waiting than you have elements in the list.